# How to delete an image I uploaded?

Tags: 7, media

When I delete an image I previously uploaded into an Image field, the file stays on my server. It takes up space and remains publicly viewable.

Is there an easy way to get Drupal to clean up after itself by deleting uploaded files that are no longer in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images should be deleted automatically during cron runs, if they are not used anymore. Meaning, their file_usage count is 0.

Comment: It didn't. Should I file a bugreport?

Comment: First look in the file_managed for the fid of your file and then in file_usage if there is an entry for it and if so, for what.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to use https://drupal.org/project/imce, since cron fails to do it.

Just delete the image from imce dialog( eg. plugin for ckeditor), with admin privileges in order to see all files

This is safe....If the image is used by another entity in drupal, imce prevents the deletion with the message *image is used by another application*